# Delete Consecutively Repeated String

Tags: string-manipulation

I have the following text:

```
text = {"hello","hello","hello","c","a","e","e","hello","hello"}
```

Now I would like to do the following:

Delete every string that is "hello" and repeats itself consecutively.

Result:

```
text = {"hello","c","a","e","e","hello"}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For version 11.3:

```
SequenceReplace[text, {"hello" ..} -> "hello"]
```

One approach for the versions older than 11.3:

```
Split[text] /. {"hello" ..} -> "hello" // Flatten
```

Comment: Very nice ! Thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: @james With pleasure :).

Answer (score 5):

Also

```
ReplaceRepeated[text, {a___, Longest["hello" ..], b___} :> {a, "hello", b}]
```

> {"hello", "c", "a", "e", "e", "hello"}

Comment: This also works. But why some codes (`a___`, `Longest`, `b___`) in my notebook turn red?

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ, i don't get that in version 9 or version 11.3.

Answer (score 5):

Since V 13.1 there is `DeleteAdjacentDuplicates`:

```
DeleteAdjacentDuplicates[text, ## == "hello" &]
```

{"hello", "c", "a", "e", "e", "hello"}